# Index Method for an Array-Backed List

Tags: python, data-structures

I am attempting to finish the construction of an Array-Backed List utilizing NumPy. This particular method is giving me troubles and I can't diagnose the issue.

```
def index(self, value, i=0, j=None):
    """Returns the index of the first instance of value encountered in
    this list between index i (inclusive) and j (exclusive). If j is not
    specified, search through the end of the list for value. If value
    is not in the list, raise a ValueError."""
    if j is None:
        j = self.size
    for idx in range(i, j):
        if self.data[idx] == value:
            return idx
    raise ValueError()
```

This is what is returned by the test:

```
self = [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1], value = 2, i = 4, j = -1

    def index(self, value, i=0, j=None):
       
        if j is None:
            j = self.size
        for idx in range(i, j):
            if self.data[idx] == value:
                return idx
>       raise ValueError()
E       ValueError

arraylist.py:168: ValueError
```

Comment: What kind of trouble? What's wrong?

Comment: Is `self.size` a typo for `self.data.size`?

Comment: See [MRE]......

Comment: I hope this is merely an exercise, because making an arraylist backed by numpy is not reasonable in any practical situation I can think of (where you would just use a python `list` which will be better than anything you can create in CPython itself)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yes it is an exercise

Comment: `self` cannot be a list, because lists don't have a `size` attribute. Please provide code we can copy, paste, and run *as is*: don't just describe your example using what amounts to pseudocode.

Comment: @chepner not sure what you mean here. for some list type, a `size` attribute makes perfect sense. Indeed, this is how `list` is implemented, but it is exposed via `__len__` and not directly, but I agree with your overall point

Comment: The `list` type created by a list display absolutely does not  have a `size` attribute. Maybe `self = [1,2,...]` is supposed to be a lazy way of saying that `self` will be an instance of some still-unspecified class, but OP should be *explicit* about what code is actually being executed.

Comment: @chepner yes, they are being lazy by not providing a [mcve], but I think they means `self.data = [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1]` somewhere, and `self.size` is probably some attribute they are manually keeping track of

Comment: Those assumptions, though, don't explain the `ValueError`, unless maybe `self.size < self.data.size` and the loop isn't iterating over the intended range. (As it turns out, that made me notice the OP is attempting to generate the list of indices to search by passing -1 to `range`, which won't work as expected.)

Answer (score 0):

> `self = [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1], value = 2, i = 4, j = -1`

Your code is iterating over `range(i, j) == range(4, -1)`. `-1` does not have the same meaning as an argument to `range` as it does as a list index:

```
> list(range(4, -1))
[]
```

(`range` doesn't know what you are *doing* with the values it produces; it certainly doesn't know about `self.data` and what an index of `-1` would actually mean.)

You are iterating over an empty sequence of indices, so you never check if *any* element is equal to 2; the loop body never executes, and you immediately raise a `ValueError`.

You can accept a negative `j`, but you'll have to convert that to an explicit upper bound for `range` that is compatible with the actual list, something like

```
if j is None:
    j = self.size
elif j < 0:
    j = self.size + j
```

The simpler solution, though, is to not generate indices in the first place, but to iterate over a slice, which *can* use `None` as a valid upper bound directly.

```
def index(self, value, i=0, j=None):
    for idx, v in enumerate(self.data[i:j], start=i):
        if v == value:
            return idx
    raise ValueError()
```